# Can someone confirm that Android still doesn't expose BLE advertising channel get/set settings?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I'd like to be able to set the specific advertising channel in an Android app that listens on a set channel for legacy BLE advertisements. (e.g. only listen to channel 37)

I couldn't find anything in the Android developer guide and I've seen some other dated posts from 4-5 years ago that say it isn't exposed.  It'd be great if someone with Android BLE experience can confirm this or point me in the right direction.  I believe the alternative would be to pursue some lower level chipset such as Nordic or TI parts and use development tools they have.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't supported (yet). As you might have already seen, this parameter is not exposed when setting the advertising settings:-

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertisingSetParameters

As you mentioned, your alternative would be to use something like TI or Nordic to get the job done. I have used Nordic devices extensively and can recommend them in terms of resources and support. For the specific channel mask setting feature, you can find details here:-

https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/33591/softdevice-s140-v6-0-0-how-to-set-the-channel-mask-for-different-channels/129182#129182

I hope this helps.

Comment: My particular use case is using Android as the central and listener or scanner of low energy advertisements.  If they add the ability to listen/scan a particular advertising channel, I would expect it to be in the ScanSettings somewhere. [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/ScanSettings).